# Representing a network in Python

Tags: python, graph-theory

I have a vertices such as `dic = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'n':6, 'm':7, 'g':8}` and i have two columns as follows represent the relationship between the vertices :

```
a a
b d
e f
c f
n f
m g
```

I want to associate each vertex in the first column with the corresponding vertex in the second column by an edge. So `a` with `a` is represent a loop. `b` with `d` is fine. `e`,`c` and `n` they are sharing the same vertex `f`. Instead  to say `e` with `f`, `c` with `f` and `n` with `f` we can say `e`, `c` and `n` with `f`.

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171/what-is-the-most-efficient-graph-data-structure-in-python

Comment: Note that there are more than one way to represent a graph, independent of the language.

Answer (score 5):

See:  https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

```
graph = {
    'a' : [ 'a' ],
    'b' : [ 'd' ],
    'c' : [ 'f' ],
    'd' : [],
    'e' : [ 'f' ],
    'f' : [],
    'g' : [],
    'm' : [ 'g' ],
    'n' : [ 'f' ]
}

print [ vertex for vertex, edges in graph.items() if 'f' in edges ]
```

EDIT:

Ok, it sounds like you just want a function to build the graph from your given inputs?

Something like this:

```
def build_graph( vertices, edges ):
    graph = dict( (v, list()) for v in vertices.keys() )
    for a, b in edges:
        graph[ a ].append( b )
    return graph
```

If you need help parsing your columnar data into a list of two-tuples then that's a different question entirely

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in your link the function determine a path between two nodes. My problem i have more than 40,000 nodes and  i want to establishment my graph. Verteices = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'n':6, 'm':7, 'g':8, ... up to z:40,000} a a
b d
e f
c f
n f
m g

Answer (score 0):

The general alternative to @kurosch's answer (adjacency list) is called an adjacency matrix.  It's simply a matrix representing every possible edge where 1 indicates presence of an edge, 0 not.

```
adj = [[0 for x in range(len(dic)] for x in range(len(dic))]
adj[dic['a'][dic['b']] = 1
etc..
```

Comment: you are right, but i use graph-tool, so i am looking for a function to build my huge graph