# How do we represent a network as a dictionary in Python when using networkx?

Tags: python, dictionary, graph-theory

This [documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.6/reference/introduction.html#data-structure) of `netowrkx` says that it accepts the data structure that looks like a `dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries`.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258494/representing-a-network-in-python) post but I could not figure out the way of representing it in the way acceptable to `networkx`.

Suppose I have a case where I have a `user_no` and corresponding `user_no`s which are actually his friends. How can I represent it like a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're linking the networkx documentation of version 1.6 whereas the current version is 1.8.1.

I recommend rather thinking about what type of graph you need, i.e., single undirected edges between your nodes, choose a `networkx.Graph`, multiple directed edges, choose a `networkx.MultiDiGraph` (`DiGraph` and `MultiGraph` also exist).

You can then use the `add_edge` or `add_edges_from` methods and they will generate the underlying data structure for you, for example,

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> net = nx.Graph()
>>> net.add_edge("user_42", "user_9", trust=9)
>>> net.adj
{'user_42': {'user_9': {'trust': 9}}, 'user_9': {'user_42': {'trust': 9}}}
```

Comment: My bad, this was done from the top of my head. When you use the `nx.Graph` class it *is* undirected which is represented by both edges being present. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See networkx documentation -

```
d={0: {1: 1}} # dict-of-dicts single edge (0,1)
G=nx.Graph(d)
```

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/convert.html